# Why Django crispy form hidden fields appear?

Tags: django, python-2.7, layout, django-crispy-forms

I have a model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    normal = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    other = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    hidden = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
```

If I define a regular form without using `exclude`, the hidden field shows up on the UI after the submit button in the DOM (and UI):

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('normal', 'hidden')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(form=self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-3 col-md-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-9 col-md-10'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'normal',
            Hidden('hidden', 'hidden initial'),
            FormActions(
                Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='save-entry btn-success'),
            )
        )
```

Now if I flip things around and assemble a basically equivalent form but using `exclude`, the hidden field doesn't appear (which is what we want).

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('other',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(form=self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-3 col-md-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-9 col-md-10'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'normal',
            Hidden('hidden', 'hidden initial'),
            FormActions(
                Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='save-entry btn-success'),
            )
        )
```

I cannot wrap my head around why is that happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Hidden` layout is used to create a hidden input.  You can add any `Hidden` element even if it is not declared in your form.  In your case, if you inspect element, you can see that there is a hidden input called `hidden`.

What you need to do instead of using the `Hidden` layout, you need to do something like this:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('normal', 'hidden',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper(form=self)
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-sm-3 col-md-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-sm-9 col-md-10'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'normal',
            Field('hidden', type='hidden'),
            FormActions(
                Submit('save', 'Save', css_class='save-entry btn-success'),
            )
        )
```

Comment: If you don't need to get/alter the value of the field, then it would be better to just exclude it from the form.